# ios xml NSString to longitude

Tags: ios, xml, nsstring, coordinates

I have tried every way I can think of with this, but just not getting it.

I have a XML file that has entries like these...

```
<lat>53.358242</lat>
<lon>-6.227800</lon>
```

The file is parsed with NSXMLParser and get the other stuff out, but just can't feed these into the annotation to drop a pin.
In the .h file I have the following;

```
@interface LocationList : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *loc_name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lat;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lon;
```

Then I try to convert the NSString to the coordinate with..

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pinCoordinate;
pinCoordinate.latitude = [theLocationList.lat doubleValue]; 
pinCoordinate.longitude = [theLocationList.lon doubleValue];
```

But I end up with 0.

I tried this, but it couldn't handle the negative value.

```
NSString *digits = [theLocationList.lon stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
NSLog(@"Attempts: %f", [digits floatValue]);
```

Anyone that can give me a dig out?

Comment: If you NSLog theLocationList.lat or theLocationList.lon what does it print out as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight change to your solution should do the trick - replace `decimalDigitCharacterSet` with `characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-0123456789."`, like this:

```
NSString *digits = [theLocationList.lon stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-0123456789."] invertedSet]];
NSLog(@"Attempts: %f", [digits floatValue]);
```